# Localhost Admin and Frontend not working after importing db dump from Staging

Tags: extensions, localhost, xampp, magento-admin

I have successfully created a database dump from my staging environment and trying to set up a local dev environment using this db dump.
When I imported the db, and set up everything, I have changed the:

```
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_url
```

In the database, but still when I open the frontend, I can see no products, no images/media at all. On the admin side, I have no icons, no extensions, and I can't click on anything other than the marketplace.
[image: Magento Admin]

Any help would be much appreciated for the best practices to configure the local dev environment as the staging environment we have.
Best,

Comment: Open console and check the path of css files and images are right or wrong